# SelectCommand error:Validation(ASP.NET) If this attribute value is enclosed en quotation marks, the quotation marks must match

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I made this query in sqlserver and when i put in my project the first line apppears in green with that error in title and after the third line it seems is no longer inside the SelectCommand because it's in red letters. I think it's about < or maybe ''. How can i fix it? Thank you

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_order" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
                        ConnectionString="myconnection"
                        SelectCommand=
                        "SELECT SUM(Total) as Totais, DateCreated, 
                         CASE 
                             WHEN DAY(DateCreated) <=15 THEN CAST(YEAR(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + '-1' 
                             ELSE CAST(YEAR(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(MONTH(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + '-16' 
                         END AS Month              
                         FROM Orders
                         WHERE ReferenceID = @refid 
                         GROUP BY DateCreated" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_ref_type" Name="refid" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to replace the single quotes and less than within the query with XML entity references `&quot;` and `&lt;` so that the XML is well-formed:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds_order" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
                        ConnectionString="myconnection"
                        SelectCommand=
                        "SELECT SUM(Total) as Totais, DateCreated, 
                         CASE 
                             WHEN DAY(DateCreated) &lt;=15 THEN CAST(YEAR(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + &quot;-&quot; + CAST(MONTH(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + &quot;-1&quot; 
                             ELSE CAST(YEAR(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + &quot;-&quot; + CAST(MONTH(DateCreated) AS VARCHAR) + &quot;-16&quot; 
                         END AS Month              
                         FROM Orders
                         WHERE ReferenceID = @refid 
                         GROUP BY DateCreated" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_ref_type" Name="refid" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```